# Use CGAL built-in number type

Tags: cgal

I'm working with `Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_Kernel` in a iOS platform. GMP doesn't support iOS so I need to use the CGAL built-in number type. How I should proceed ?

**EDIT**

Setting XCode environment variable `CGAL_DISABLE_GMP` to `ON` and removing library from xcodeproj works.

Comment: Define CGAL_DISABLE_GMP (in the environment or CMake).

Comment: @MarcGlisse what value? I can't find information in [CGAL doc](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/configurationvariables.html) I tried 1, TRUE, YES, ON without success...

Comment: I would guess ON since I see `if($ENV{CGAL_DISABLE_GMP}) set(CGAL_DISABLE_GMP ON CACHE INTERNAL "")`.